# Scala Dataframe : How can I add a column to a Dataframe using a condition between two Dataframes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two Dataframe:

```
- UsersDF: (column_name:type) => [ (name,String) (age,Int) (Like,Int) ]
 - ClusterDF: => [(cluster,bigInt)  (names,String)]
```

A row of clusterDF's names column is composed of a user string separated from the space character `("\ t").`
Users are in one cluster.

I would like to add the cluster column to the userDF Dataframe, inspecting the field names. How could I do?

Example:

row of clusterDF: `1, "A B C D"`

row of userDF: `"A", 23, 150`

At the end of the process: row of userDF: `"A", 23, 150, 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to join the two dataframes. For this you need two steps. The first is to convert clusterDF to a usable form:

```
val fixed = clusterDF.withColumn("name", explode(split($"names", " ")))
```

We first split the names by space to get an array of names and then explode it to get a row for each value.

Now just join the two:

```
usersDF.join(fixed, "name")
```

Comment: In the end I resolved. The code is similar to yours;)